# Tapping into the Magento module loading sequence?

Tags: extensions

Is there a hack-free customization point in Magento 1.X that allows us to listen to when modules are loaded (or other parts of the initialization sequence)?

I define 'hack-free' above as not modifying and/or rewriting the core.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I define 'hack-free' above as not modifying and/or rewriting the core.

This would require a module but it cannot do anything before it is loaded, so: no,